# Kivy UrlRequest doesn't trigger callback

Tags: python, callback, garbage-collection, kivy

This is a minimal version of what I'm trying to do. This is my `main.py` file:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__()
        self.url_input = TextInput()
        self.start = Button(text='Download')

        self.start.bind(on_release=partial(self.on_start_press))
        self.add_widget(self.url_input)
        self.add_widget(self.start)

    def on_start_press(self, *args):
        DownloadTask(self.url_input.text)
        ...
```

And this is my task.py file that contains the `DownloadTask`.

```
class DownloadTask(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self._get_headers()

    def _get_headers(self):
        UrlRequest(url=self.url, on_success=self._on_headers_fetched, method='HEAD')

    def _on_headers_fetched(self, req, resp):
        self.content_length = int(req.resp_headers.get('Content-Length'))
```

But the on_success callback is never called. On line 439 of `urlrequest.py`:

```
if self.on_success:
    func = self.on_success()
        if func:
            func(self, data)
```

`func` is `None` so no callback is called. Also line 47 in `weakmethod.py` raises `ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists` when trying to access `self.proxy`.

```
try:
    if self.proxy:
        return getattr(self.proxy, self.method_name)
except ReferenceError:
    pass
return self.method
```

What is the issue here? Is my `DownloadTask()` object garbage collected?

Environemnt: Python 3.5.3, Kivy 1.10.0, mac os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** After the [source](https://github.com/eteamin/Exmoore/blob/b01df0ce5bfab9d38849877f76e3e6e0b2127cab/main.py#L38) was revealed, it appears to me that the `DownloadTask` object was garbage-collected, therefore the `Thread` ran by `UrlRequest` [called](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/83ec08750babec892d1fd46c2f14b292b5144ed6/kivy/network/urlrequest.py#L184) a [`WeakProxy`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.weakproxy.html) for a method of an object that doesn't exist - therefore crash.

---

Whether it was garbage-collected or not I'm not sure, however the request creates a daemon `Thread`, therefore you shouldn't care that much (feel free to find out). There's a [comment](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/83ec08750babec892d1fd46c2f14b292b5144ed6/kivy/network/urlrequest.py#L244) about it, so it probably isn't collected *yet*.

The `UrlRequest` however strongly depends on Kivy and that's visible [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/83ec08750babec892d1fd46c2f14b292b5144ed6/kivy/network/urlrequest.py#L182). It uses Kivy [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html). This means that unless the Kivy application is run, the request won't proceed further i.e. it should stop [on this line](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/83ec08750babec892d1fd46c2f14b292b5144ed6/kivy/network/urlrequest.py#L240). Just try to add any `print('something')` to the `UrlRequest._dispatch_result()` and you'll see it's completely ignored, because Kivy `Clock` isn't ticking (therefore the function isn't called).

However with this example, where the actual Kivy application is run I don't see a problem with it.

```
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest

class My(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(My, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        UrlRequest(
            url='http://lipsum.com/',
            on_error=lambda *args: print('error:', args),
            on_failure=lambda *args: print('fail:', args),
            on_redirect=lambda *args: print('redir:', args),
            on_success=lambda *args: print('success:', args)
        )

runTouchApp(My())
```

Comment: Actually `UrlRequest._dispatch_result()` is called. And Im not calling this code out of a kivy app context. this is the source if you want to see. https://github.com/eteamin/Exmoore/blob/master/models/task.py
and this is the main file https://github.com/eteamin/Exmoore/blob/master/main.py

Comment: I see. Then in [this case](https://github.com/eteamin/Exmoore/blob/b01df0ce5bfab9d38849877f76e3e6e0b2127cab/main.py#L38) I believe your *`DownloadTask`* object is collected.

Comment: Also if I set a function instead of a method as callback, the function will be called

Comment: Try to change `DownloadTask(...)` to `self.task = DownloadTask(...)` and see what happens.

Comment: I did as so and it is not collected anymore! Thanks. could you elaborate on this?

Comment: See edit above and please **include** that part of code to your question, so that other people can find it later. I don't trust GitHub's permalinks (repo can be deleted).